# Minimum polynomial and matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

May you help me with the following proving?

> Let $A,B$ be square matrices over $\mathbb C$ and suppose that there exist rectangular matrices $P,Q$ over $\mathbb C$ such that $A=PQ$ and $B=QP$.
>
> If $h(X)$ is any polynomial with complex coefficients, prove that $Ah(A)=Ph(B)Q$.
>
> Hence show that $Am_B(A)=0=Bm_B(B)$. Deduce that one of the following holds: $$m_A(X)=m_B(X),~~ m_A(X)=Xm_B(X),~~ m_B(X)=Xm_A(X).$$

At the notes on how to answer are mentioned that $(PQ)^{i+1}=P(QP)^iQ$, how is that possible?
$$$$ **Added:** May you help me with the deduction part? $m_A(X)$ stands for minimum polynomial

> Deduce that one of the following holds: $$m_A(X)=m_B(X),~~ m_A(X)=Xm_B(X),~~ m_B(X)=Xm_A(X).$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $(PQ)^{i+1}=PQPQPQ\dots PQ=P(QPQPQP\dots QP)Q=P(QP)^{i}Q$

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The equality $$(PQ)^{i+1}=P(QP)^iQ\tag{eq}$$ stems from the fact that on both sides we have the product of $i+1$ copies of $PQ$.

So if $h(X) = c_0 + c_1 X + \dots + c_n X^n$, we have, using (eq)
$$
P h(B) Q = P (c_0 I + c_1 B + \dots + c_n B^n) Q
=
P h(B) Q = P (c_0 I + c_1 QP + \dots + c_n (QP)^n) Q.
= a_0 PQ + a_1 (PQ)^2 + \dots +  c_n (QP)^{n+1}
= a_0 A + a_1 A^2 + \dots +  c_n A^{n+1}
= A h(A).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Is there something special about $A,B$ being over $\mathbb C$ and not $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @proofy, you're welcome, it seems to me that this works for matrices over an arbitrary field.

Comment: Thank you very much again!

Comment: @proofy, you're welcome!

Comment: @ Andreas Caranti I will be grateful if you may refer to the added part.